# Dynamically populate a single field based on dropdown selections (Javascript / HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dynamically-generated

Im trying to get a part code generator by using multiple dropdown boxes which have multiple selection within each dropdown box. Id like to return the results into one field.

Code below generates each dropdown box into its on input field but i'd like it to amalgamate the information and build it as each dropdown box is selected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Pre populated array of data
var myData = new Array();
myData[1] = 'JUN LED39 W';
  myData[2] = 'JUNO LED76 W';
myData[3] = 'P';
myData[4] = 'O';
myData[5] = '3K DALI';
myData[6] = '4K DALI';
myData[7] = '';
myData[8] = 'E3';
</script>

<form id="example" name="example">
<select id="lumen" name="lumen">
    <option value="" selected>lumen</option>
    <option value=1>3888lm</option>
    <option value=2>7666lm</option>
</select>
  <select id="diffuser" name="Diffuser">
    <option value="" selected>diffuser</option>
    <option value=3>Prismatic</option>
    <option value=4>Opal</option>
</select>
 </select>
  <select id="cct" name="cct">
    <option value="" selected>cct</option>
    <option value=5>3000k</option>
    <option value=6>4000k</option>
</select>
 <select id="em3" name="em3">
    <option value="" selected>emergency</option>
    <option value=7>No</option>
    <option value=8>Yes</option>
</select>
<br />
<input type="text" value="" id="answer1" name="answer1" />
  <input type="text" value="" id="answer2" name="answer2" />
    <input type="text" value="" id="answer3" name="answer3" />
      <input type="text" value="" id="answer4" name="answer4" />

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.example.lumen.onchange = updateText;
document.example.diffuser.onchange = updateText;
document.example.cct.onchange = updateText;
document.example.em3.onchange = updateText;

function updateText() {
  var obj_sel = document.example.lumen;
  document.example.answer1.value = myData[obj_sel.value];
  var obj_sel = document.example.diffuser;
  document.example.answer2.value = myData[obj_sel.value];
  var obj_sel = document.example.cct;
  document.example.answer3.value = myData[obj_sel.value];
  var obj_sel = document.example.em3;
  document.example.answer4.value = myData[obj_sel.value];
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the display value of the input fields to 'none' and change this as they are filled.

```js
document.example.lumen.onchange = updateText;
document.example.diffuser.onchange = updateText;
document.example.cct.onchange = updateText;
document.example.em3.onchange = updateText;

function updateText() {
  var obj_sel = document.example.lumen;
  var lumen = myData[obj_sel.value] || '';
  
  var obj_sel = document.example.diffuser;
  var diffuser = myData[obj_sel.value] || '';
  
  var obj_sel = document.example.cct;
  var cct = myData[obj_sel.value] || '';
  
  var obj_sel = document.example.em3;
  var em3 = myData[obj_sel.value] || '';
  
  document.example.answer.value = `${lumen}    ${diffuser}    ${cct}    ${em3}`;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Pre populated array of data
  var myData = new Array();
  myData[1] = 'JUN LED39 W';
  myData[2] = 'JUNO LED76 W';
  myData[3] = 'P';
  myData[4] = 'O';
  myData[5] = '3K DALI';
  myData[6] = '4K DALI';
  myData[7] = '';
  myData[8] = 'E3';
</script>

<form id="example" name="example">
  <select id="lumen" name="lumen">
    <option value="" selected>lumen</option>
    <option value=1>3888lm</option>
    <option value=2>7666lm</option>
  </select>
  <select id="diffuser" name="Diffuser">
    <option value="" selected>diffuser</option>
    <option value=3>Prismatic</option>
    <option value=4>Opal</option>
  </select>
  <select id="cct" name="cct">
    <option value="" selected>cct</option>
    <option value=5>3000k</option>
    <option value=6>4000k</option>
  </select>
  <select id="em3" name="em3">
    <option value="" selected>emergency</option>
    <option value=7>No</option>
    <option value=8>Yes</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <input type="text" value="" id="answer" name="answer" style="width: 100%" />

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas however this populates each answer in its own field with answers aligned vertically on top of each other. I'd like to achieve having all dropdown box answers just in one answer field so it populates the part code as it goes along in just one field and not a field per dropbox. i hope i'm making sense?

Comment: or can the results go back to populate horizontally without cell borders and the text is close together so rather than it populate and look like JUN LED39 W  (Large space)            P (large space)          4K DALI it looks like JUN LED39 W (one spacebar) P (one spacebar)4K DALI (one spacebar) E3. This would achieve a string of text as if it was written together like "JUN LED39 W P 4K DALI E3"

Comment: Yes that is possible, I have modified the answer to adapt it to your request.

Comment: Perfect! finally can the spacing between the text in the answer field be reduce just to a single space between each segment?